# preprocessing RIPEMD-160

Tags: python, cryptography

is the padding of RIPEMD-160 exactly the same as MD4 padding, down to the little-endian change?

if i input "abc" in ascii, the processed data in hex should be 8063626100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001800000000

right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, per the good pseudocode file found [here](http://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~bosselae/ripemd/rmd128.txt) (for ripemd-128, but ripemd-160 just extends that),

```
Padding is identical to that of MD4.
```